# MySQL QUERY SUM() with subquery

Tags: mysql

I have a simple request that I can't figure in MySQL :

With my query I got this :

```
TABLEA
+----+----------+
| id | quantity |
+----+----------+
|  1 |        2 |
|  2 |        5 |
|  3 |        7 |
|  4 |        4 |
+----+----------+

Select id, Quantity From tableA
```

And I want this :

```
TABLE A
+----+------------+--------+
| id | quantity   | total  |
+----+------------+--------+
|  1 |          2 | 18     |
|  2 |          5 | 18     |
|  3 |          7 | 18     |
|  4 |          4 | 18     |
+----+------------+--------+

Select id, Quantity, SUM(quantity) total From tableA
```

But I don't want to do this

```
Select id, Quantity, FROM tableA
JOIN select SUM(quantity) total FROM tableA
```

Because tableA is already a subquery in my code and it take some time.

any idea ?

EDIT : I use JOIN for my example but I want to avoid all query using "FROM tableA" again

EDIT 2 :

```
TABLE A
+----+------------+--------+
| id | quantity   | total  |
+----+------------+--------+
|  1 |          2 | 7      |
|  1 |          5 | 7      |
|  2 |          7 | 11     |
|  2 |          4 | 11     |
+----+------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to do a subselect

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.Quantity,
    (SELECT SUM(b.quantity) FROM tableA b)
FROM
    tableA a
```

edit: Otherwise you could create yourself a view in mysql with the above subselect and then join with that table.

Comment: I know this answer but is there a way not to do "FROM TABLEA" again ?

Comment: Non that I know of, because you try to use an aggregate function on a table but at the same time you try to get the single items

Comment: In fact I better want that see edit 2, but you may right there is no solution

Answer (score 0):

Use two select statements, store the sum into a variable:

select sum(quantity) into @sum_quantity from tableA; select id,quantity,@sum_quantity total from tableA

here, the aggregate function is executed once.